# Ansible/Jinja2 template : for loop runs twice

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have a problem with a for loop in my Jinja2 file.
I use Ansible template as the following :

```
- name: "Configure syslog-ng-nginx"
  template:
    src: "nginx.conf.j2"
    dest: /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/nginx.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0640
    backup: yes
  with_dict: "{{ nginx_http_template }}"
  notify: restart syslog-ng
```

My dict looks like this :

```
nginx_http_template:
  toto.test.fr:
    conf_file_name: toto.test.fr
    conf_file_location: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
    servers:
      server1:
        server_name: 'toto.test.fr'
        listen:
          listen_wildcard:
            ip: '*'
            port: 80
        access_log:
          - name: main
            location: /var/log/nginx/access.toto.test.fr.log
        error_log:
          location: /var/log/nginx/error.toto.test.fr.log
          level: warn
        autoindex: false
        root: /var/www/toto/public
  toto2.test.fr:
    conf_file_name: toto2.test.fr
    conf_file_location: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
    servers:
      server1:
        server_name: 'toto2.test.fr'
        listen:
          listen_wildcard:
            ip: '*'
            port: 80
        access_log:
          - name: main
            location: /var/log/nginx/access.toto2.test.fr.log
        error_log:
          location: /var/log/nginx/error.toto2.test.fr.log
          level: warn
        autoindex: false
        root: /var/www/toto2/public
```

And my `nginx.conf.j2`template looks like this :

```
source {{ nginx_syslog_source_name }} {
{% for server in item.value.servers %}
  {% for access_log in item.value.servers[server].access_log %}
    file("{{ access_log.location }}" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-{{ item.value.servers[server].server_name }}"));
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
};
```

The problem is, whenever I run the task, the file is getting written with the informations of "toto.test.fr", but then, instead of "appending" the informations of "toto2.test.fr", it overwrites the "toto.test.fr" and I only get what's in "toto2.test.fr".

Let's have a look at my Ansible output :

```
TASK [syslog : Configure syslog-ng-nginx] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
--- before
+++ after: /home/yanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-251749PRAOO/tmpIR53tK/nginx.conf.j2
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+source s_nginx_toto.test {
+      file("/var/log/nginx/access.toto.test.fr.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-toto.test.fr"));
+  };

changed: [MYHOST] => (item={'value': {u'conf_file_name': u'toto.test.fr', u'conf_file_location': u'/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/', u'servers': {u'server1': {u'error_lo
g': {u'location': u'/var/log/nginx/error.toto.test.fr.log', u'level': u'warn'}, u'server_name': u'toto.test.fr', u'autoindex': False, u'access_log': [{u'name': u'main', u'locati
on': u'/var/log/nginx/access.toto.test.fr.log'}], u'root': u'/var/www/toto/public', u'listen': {u'listen_wildcard': {u'ip': u'*', u'port': 80}}}}}, 'key': u'toto.test.fr'})

--- before: /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/nginx.conf
+++ after: /home/yanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-251749PRAOO/tmpRaaSpL/nginx.conf.j2
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 source s_nginx_toto_test {
-      file("/var/log/nginx/access.toto.test.fr.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-toto.test.fr"));
+      file("/var/log/nginx/access.toto2.test.fr.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-toto2.test.fr"));
   };

changed: [MYHOST] => (item={'value': {u'conf_file_name': u'toto2.test.fr', u'conf_file_location': u'/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/', u'servers': {u'server1': {u'error_l
og': {u'location': u'/var/log/nginx/error.toto2.test.fr.log', u'level': u'warn'}, u'server_name': u'toto2.test.fr', u'autoindex': False, u'access_log': [{u'name': u'main', u'loc
ation': u'/var/log/nginx/access.toto2.test.fr.log'}], u'root': u'/var/www/toto2/public', u'listen': {u'listen_wildcard': {u'ip': u'*', u'port': 80}}}}}, 'key': u'toto2.test.fr'}
)
```

As you can see, the "toto.test.fr" infos get written, but then, the "toto2.test.fr" also get written and overwrite the "toto.test.fr".

Here he's the final file :

```
source s_nginx_toto_test {
      file("/var/log/nginx/access.toto2.test.fr.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-toto2.test.fr"));
  };
```

What I want is :

```
source s_nginx_toto_test {
      file("/var/log/nginx/access.toto.test.fr.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-toto.test.fr"));
  };
      file("/var/log/nginx/access.toto2.test.fr.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-toto2.test.fr"));
  };
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop `﻿with_dict: "{{ nginx_http_template }}"`, generate file */etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/nginx.conf* with key `toto.test.fr` then generate same file with key `toto2.test.fr`.

To solve your problem, remove loop from task :

```yaml
- name: "Configure syslog-ng-nginx"
  template:
    src: "nginx.conf.j2"
    dest: /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/nginx.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0640
    backup: yes
  notify: restart syslog-ng
```

And update your template to manage directly your variable `nginx_http_template`:

```
source {{ nginx_syslog_source_name }} {
{% for name, config in nginx_http_template.items() %}
    file("{{ config.servers.server1.access_log[0].location }}" flags(no-parse) program-override("nginx-access-{{ name }}"));
{% endfor %}
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked just great. I didn't know the with_dict would generate a loop ! I understand the problem know.